# Arduino multitasking using millis doesn't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to use `millis` because I need to run several loops function at the same time. One to get GPS and temperature value then send every value to user's phone number when a request received, and another to display those value on OLED. But my functions seem to be blocking each other even though I have been using `millis`. This is my code:

**initializing**

```
#include<TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DHT.h"

#include <Adafruit_ssd1306syp.h>                        
Adafruit_ssd1306syp display(A4,A5);                  

//dht
#define DHTPIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
//gps
const double Home_LAT = -6.1887;                     
const double Home_LNG = 106.7;
float glatitude;
float glongitude;
//sms  
char ReceivedSms;
short DHT_OK=-1, GPS_OK=-1;
String DataSms;
//dht
int nilaiSuhu;
int nilaiKelembaban;
//millis
unsigned long counting_millis;
unsigned long millis_now;
const unsigned long delay_val = 2000;
const unsigned long delay_val2 = 1000;

TinyGPSPlus gps;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
SoftwareSerial sim800l(2,3);
```

**void setup**

```
void setup(){
  
  sim800l.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  Serial.println("Starting..");
  delay(7000);
  ReceiveMode();

  display.initialize();                                  
  display.clear();                                      
   
}
```

**void loop**

```
void loop() {
 
  millis_now = millis();
  
  if(millis_now - counting_millis > delay_val)
  {
    oled_Display();
    counting_millis = millis_now;
  
  }
  
  if(millis_now - counting_millis > delay_val2){
    mergeFunction();
    counting_millis = millis_now;
  }
  
}
```

*oled_Display()* is a function for displaying every value on OLED

```
void oled_Display() {

      display.clear();
      display.setCursor(0,0); 
  
      float nilaiSuhu = dht.readTemperature();
      float nilaiKelembaban = dht.readHumidity();
      
      display.print("Suhu      : ");
      display.println(nilaiSuhu);
      display.print("Kelembaban: ");
      display.println(nilaiKelembaban);
      display.print("Latitude  : ");
      display.println(gps.location.lat(), 5);
      display.print("Longitude : ");
      display.println(gps.location.lng(), 4);
      display.print("Satellites: ");
      display.println(gps.satellites.value());
      display.print("Speed     : ");
      display.println(gps.speed.mph());
      
      unsigned long Distance_To_Home = (unsigned long)TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(gps.location.lat(),gps.location.lng(),Home_LAT, Home_LNG);
      display.print("KM asal   :");                        // Have TinyGPS Calculate distance to home and display it
      display.print(Distance_To_Home);
      display.update();                                       
}
```

*mergeFunction()* is a function to get GPS and temperature value, and send it to user based on request.

```
void mergeFunction(){

   nilaiSuhu = dht.readTemperature();
   nilaiKelembaban = dht.readHumidity();
   String RSMS;
  
    while(sim800l.available() > 0) {
      ReceivedSms = sim800l.read();
      Serial.print(ReceivedSms);
      RSMS.concat(ReceivedSms);
      DHT_OK = RSMS.indexOf("Suhu");
      GPS_OK = RSMS.indexOf("All");
      
    }
  
     while(Serial.available() > 0){
      if(gps.encode(Serial.read()))
        readGPS();
      
    }
  
    if(DHT_OK!=-1){
      Serial.println("DHT found");
      
      Serial.print("Temperature = ");
      Serial.print(nilaiSuhu);
      Serial.print("*C      Humidity = ");
      Serial.print(nilaiKelembaban); 
      Serial.println(" %");
  
      DataSms = "DHT11\nSuhu = "+String(nilaiSuhu,1)+" C"+" \nKelembaban ="+String(nilaiKelembaban,1)+" %";
      
      SendData();
      ReceiveMode(); 
  
      DHT_OK=-1; 
    }
     
    if(gps.location.isValid())
    { 
        glatitude = gps.location.lat();
        glongitude = gps.location.lng();
        
        String link = "http://www.google.com/maps/place/" + String(glatitude,6) + "," + String(glongitude,6);
        
        DataSms = "ALL\nSuhu = "+String(nilaiSuhu,1)+" C"+" \nKelembaban ="+String(nilaiKelembaban,1)+" %"+" \nMaps = "+link;
        if(GPS_OK!=-1)
        {
        SendData();
        ReceiveMode();
        GPS_OK = -1;
        } 
    } 
    else
    {
        if(GPS_OK!=-1)
        {
        DataSms = "ALL\nSuhu = "+String(nilaiSuhu,1)+" C"+" \nKelembaban ="+String(nilaiKelembaban,1)+" %"+" \nMaps = "+"Lokasi tidak ditemukan";
        SendData();
        ReceiveMode();
        GPS_OK = -1;
        } 
    }

}
```

Both of those function are working perfectly when they are not running at the same time. I don't know why both of my function are blocking each other when they are running at the same time even though I have been using `millis`. What is the proper way to run Arduino multitasking? Enlighten me.

Comment: Of course functions can only be run in parallel if you started them in separate threads. But you didn't create any threads, and Arduino Uno can't run multiple threads either (at least not in the easy way you expected). You need to create timers for them

Comment: besides you may have better luck on [arduino.se]

Comment: does using millis like on my void loop isn't enough?

Comment: no. there's nothing that makes the 2 if blocks running in parallel. The first one will run first and then the second

Comment: your error is that you reset the start time every time for all. you need a separate `counting_millis` for each function. and there should be no while loop in the functions. handle what is available and return. continue reading the input on next invocation of the function.

Comment: why there should be no while loop in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Statements in C++ are always executed **sequentially** from top to bottom. How can you expect 2 functions to run in parallel when they're no different from other functions?

```
oled_Display();
mergeFunction(); // this will be run only after the previous statements have finished
```

If that's the case then `setup()` or `loop()` are also run in parallel. In a normal single program only [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) are executed in parallel. However on a tiny embedded system like the Arduino multithreading isn't supported because context switch is very costly. See [How can I create multiple running threads?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/286/3606)

In computers you use [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) to wait for events instead of [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) like that which wastes a lot of cycles. One of the interrupts to run things in a timely manner is called a [timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer#Software_applications). In Arduino you can use [arduino-timer](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduino-timer/). Just set up 2 timers for the 2 procedures and wait for them to fire

Answer (score 0):

As @Juraj mentioned, you need an independent `counting_millis` variable for each function you are trying to call.

The main problem here is the misconception that:

> I need to run several loops function at the same time

which is not possible with an AVR microcontroller. It is possible to *multitask* using the `millis()` function, however that doesn't mean that both processes will occur at the *same time*.

Unless you migrate your code to an RTOS which runs based on [semaphores and queues](https://percepio.com/2016/08/11/rtos-101-semaphores-and-queues/) (yet **not** in parallel) you cannot achieve that parallelization. Having said that, you might need to rethink your problem in terms of **priorities**.

I would personally print data on the OLED **after** the data from the GPS has been processed. This is completely based on recent experience while developing a complex system that queries a bunch of sensors, user inputs, and serial communication. The last thing you want to deal with is the OLED since the most important part (I assume) is getting the relevant data to be displayed.

I suggest refreshing the screen every 40(-ish) milliseconds, corresponding to an approximate minimum refresh rate of 24 frames per second, which is what the human eye comfortable can detect as smooth movement. This is not accounting for the time the library takes to send data to the OLED. However, in the end, you won't see any impact on your performance if you do that.

Comment: I have tried to use RTOS but still doesn't work. I think it caused by the storage limit of my MCU (Arduino uno) too, it only has 2Kb RAM and the whole program consumed more than 50% of the storage space. Regardless of the size of the OLED module, the SSD1306 driver has a built-in 1KB Graphic Display Data RAM (GDDRAM) for the screen which holds the bit pattern to be displayed. I'm going to assume that my OLED lack of storage to buffer the whole display.

Comment: What I have done is change my library to run the OLED and create a schedule using simple-timer library. Now the whole program just consumed 47% of the storage space. Yes it works for several minutes and then being freeze :D. I think I have to change my MCU